# Creating notification in android app

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am creating my first android app and I need some help creating a simple notification using a button. Once the button is pressed I would like a notification to appear with a custom message after a set time. I would like the notification to appear regardless of what the user is doing. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In android there is a way called toast method.

in your button click event

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!!     =)",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// popup keep long time


Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//popup keep short time
```

Since youre begginer I will provide full code.

//in your mainactivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          //Toast method 
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast                message!!! =)",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

    });

  }

}

//In your  res/layout/main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button - Go to mkyong.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```